# Конфликт прокси и куки

Tags: c#, cookie

Что не так с моим кодом? Если я запускаю приложения с прокси оно не дает мне нормальные куксы. Если я отключу прокси, я получу норм куксы. Мб что-то с кодом не так?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sites);

req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(sites);

WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);
myproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("log", "pass");
req.Proxy = myproxy;

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

Upd.

```
    public static CookieContainer GetUriCookieContainer(Uri uri)
{
   CookieContainer cookies = null;
   // Determine the size of the cookie
   int datasize = 8192 * 16;
   StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
   if (!InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), null, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero))
   {
      if (datasize < 0)
         return null;
      // Allocate stringbuilder large enough to hold the cookie
      cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
      if (!InternetGetCookieEx(
                uri.ToString(),
                null, cookieData,
                ref datasize,
                InternetCookieHttponly,
                IntPtr.Zero))
                return null;
    }
    if (cookieData.Length > 0)
    {
       cookies = new CookieContainer();
       cookies.SetCookies(uri, cookieData.ToString().Replace(';', ','));
    }
    return cookies;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код вполне нормально работает с гугл, и прокси найденом в интернете. Возможно проблема в методе GetUriCookieContainer ? А так же зачем два раза присваивать куки контейнер ?

Comment: @QertuUerty посмотрите я апдейтнул

Comment: Возможно ваше прокси не работает с куки. Попробуйте вывести список отправленных и принятых заголовков. Накидал код для вашего удобства:http://paste.ubuntu.com/23502440/

Comment: @QertuUerty проверю как только установиться обновление к студии. Что должно вывести если все нормально, и что - если не все нормально?

Comment: Если нормально, должно вывестись Set-Cookie : ВАША_КУКИ_ЗДЕСЬ . Рекомендую сначала вывести только хеадеры в запросе, т.е. второй цикл.

Comment: @QertuUerty отличие от куки req От resp в том что в resp xxxxLogin=deleted, а там deleted нету, в чем проблема?

Comment: @QertuUerty http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593435/httpwebresponse-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8 посмотрите пожалуйста