# HttpWebResponse не хочет принимать куки

Tags: c#, cookie

Здравствуйте. Почему у меня HttpWebResponse не принимает куки с cookiecontainer если использовать прокси? Хотя в cookiecontainer все куки записаны.

Вот так работает.

```
 req.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(sites);
 HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

А так нет:

```
string MyProxyHostString = "5.8.37.185";
int MyProxyPort = 8085;
req.Proxy = new WebProxy(MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);
```

Заметил вот такую фишку:

```
REq:Cookie : _ga=GA1.2.1317698739.1478508335; timezoneOffset=7200; 0=; steamMachineAuth76561198074016370=9EDC6979E6E34921705C05376A7B8C79A76581BB; sessionid=72bc6c5a8484e27ef69c8f08; steamCountry=UA%7C3ed9c2a61ac880b1eab8d501bffde73c; steamLogin=76561198074016370%7C%7CB9C44C61BE7D97EE9277CD0B6E3C962F5CC38029; steamLoginSecure=76561198074016370%7C%7C737D36C6DB42F2218D1993C5830024500A9C3E01
RESP:Set-Cookie : steamLogin=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/,steamLoginSecure=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/,steamCountry=CA%7C6eaee81cd3ee32b3a266bac227557b1a; path=/
```

Comment: Ребят, ну почему оно удаляет некоторые куки! Помогите что чем сможет

Comment: В стиме защита, чтобы ты не мог входить с других айпи. Во многом это и есть главной проблемой

Comment: @QertuUerty это никак не обойти? Ведь я ж получаю нормальные куки при реквесте, где есть всё....блин(

Comment: Я по этому поводу ничего сказать не могу, возможно и можно.